# How do I debug babel-jest for Jest's transformIgnorePatterns?

Tags: jestjs, babel-jest

I've been tweaking my `transformIgnorePatterns` settings and my computer slows to the point of crashing now in tests. It's not a great machine to begin with, but it never did this badly before.

Anyway, I'm hoping to debug how this is affecting my Jest operation. Specifically, I want to see what babel-jest is compiling when it executes so I can know if I've screwed something up. Is there any way to see that kind of debug output in the logs?